# Accessing 1 Berkeley Environment from 2 different application

Tags: berkeley-db

Can 2 or more different applications access a single Berkeley Environment at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  But, you've got to set it up properly.

> An environment may be shared by any number of processes, as well as by any number of threads within
>   those processes. It is possible for an environment to include resources from other directories on the
>   system, and applications often choose to distribute resources to other directories or disks for
>   performance or other reasons. However, by default, the databases, shared regions (the locking,
>   logging, memory pool, and transaction shared memory areas) and log files will be stored in a single
>   directory hierarchy.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17275_01/html/programmer_reference/env.html